# How to expose a headless Kafka service for a StatefulSet externally in Kubernetes

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes

Using [kubernetes-kafka](https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka) as a starting point with minikube.

This uses a StatefulSet and a [headless service](https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka/blob/master/20dns.yml) for service discovery within the cluster.

The goal is to expose the individual Kafka Brokers externally which are internally addressed as:

```
kafka-0.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092
kafka-1.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 
kafka-2.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092
```

The constraint is that this external service be able to address the brokers specifically.

Whats the right (or one possible) way of going about this? Is it possible to expose a external service per `kafka-x.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092`?

Comment: Hi, Do you think this solution can be implemented better with nginx in between, satisfying the same requirements that are you are particularly looking for. Have you tried with nginx? And can you please let me know your opinion regarding this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Solutions so far weren't quite satisfying enough for myself, so I'm going to post an answer of my own. My goals:

1. Pods should still be dynamically managed through a StatefulSet as much as possible.
2. Create an external service per Pod (i.e Kafka Broker) for Producer/Consumer clients and avoid load balancing.
3. Create an internal headless service so that each Broker can communicate with each other.

Starting with [Yolean/kubernetes-kafka](https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka), the only thing missing is exposing the service externally and two challenges in doing so.

1. Generating unique labels per Broker pod so that we can create an external service for each of the Broker pods.
2. Telling the Brokers to communicate to each other using the internal Service while configuring Kafka to tell the producer/consumers to communicate over the external Service.

**Per pod labels and external services:**

To generate labels per pod, [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44103) was really helpful. Using it as a guide, we add the following line to the [10broker-config.yml](https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka/blob/master/kafka/10broker-config.yml) `init.sh` property with:

```
kubectl label pods ${HOSTNAME} kafka-set-component=${HOSTNAME}
```

We keep the existing headless service, but we also generate an external Service per pod using the label (I added them to [20dns.yml](https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka/blob/master/kafka/20dns.yml)):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: broker-0
   namespace: kafka
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 9093
    nodePort: 30093
selector:
  kafka-set-component: kafka-0
```

**Configure Kafka with internal/external listeners**

I found [this issue](https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka/issues/13) incredibly useful in trying to understand how to configure Kafka.

This again requires updating the `init.sh` and `server.properties` properties in [10broker-config.yml](https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka/blob/master/kafka/10broker-config.yml) with the following:

Add the following to the `server.properties` to update the security protocols (currently using `PLAINTEXT`):

```
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT
```

Dynamically determine the external IP and for external port for each Pod in the `init.sh`:

```
EXTERNAL_LISTENER_IP=<your external addressable cluster ip>
EXTERNAL_LISTENER_PORT=$((30093 + ${HOSTNAME##*-}))
```

Then configure `listeners` and `advertised.listeners` IPs for `EXTERNAL_LISTENER` and `INTERNAL_LISTENER` (also in the `init.sh` property):

```
sed -i "s/#listeners=PLAINTEXT:\/\/:9092/listeners=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT:\/\/0.0.0.0:9092,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT:\/\/0.0.0.0:9093/" /etc/kafka/server.properties
sed -i "s/#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT:\/\/your.host.name:9092/advertised.listeners=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT:\/\/$HOSTNAME.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT:\/\/$EXTERNAL_LISTENER_IP:$EXTERNAL_LISTENER_PORT/" /etc/kafka/server.properties
```

Obviously, this is not a full solution for production (for example addressing security for the externally exposed brokers) and I'm still refining my understanding of how to also let internal producer/consumers to also communicate with the brokers.

However, so far this is the best approach for my understanding of Kubernetes and Kafka.

Comment: Alternative can be to use `initContainer` that writes down the external ip to local storage and the kafka container then reads from that.
https://github.com/kow3ns/kubernetes-kafka/issues/3

Comment: Did you find a way to dynamically create outside service if we scale up the pods .I am trying to automate once we increase the pods then  outside service should automatically be created

Answer (score 37):

We have solved this in 1.7 by changing the headless service to `Type=NodePort` and setting the `externalTrafficPolicy=Local`. This bypasses the internal load balancing of a Service and traffic destined to a specific node on that node port will only work if a Kafka pod is on that node.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: broker
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30000
    port: 30000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9092
  selector:
    app: broker
  type: NodePort
```

For example, we have two nodes nodeA and nodeB, nodeB is running a kafka pod. nodeA:30000 will not connect but nodeB:30000 will connect to the kafka pod running on nodeB.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-typenodeport

Note this was also available in 1.5 and 1.6 as a beta annotation, more can be found here on feature availability: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip

Note also that while this ties a kafka pod to a specific external network identity, it does not guarantee that your storage volume will be tied to that network identity. If you are using the VolumeClaimTemplates in a StatefulSet then your volumes are tied to the pod while kafka expects the volume to be tied to the network identity.

For example, if the kafka-0 pod restarts and kafka-0 comes up on nodeC instead of nodeA, kafka-0's pvc (if using VolumeClaimTemplates) has data that it is for nodeA and the broker running on kafka-0 starts rejecting requests thinking that it is nodeA not nodeC.

To fix this, we are looking forward to Local Persistent Volumes but right now we have a single PVC for our kafka StatefulSet and data is stored under `$NODENAME` on that PVC to tie volume data to a particular node.

https://github.com/kubernetes/features/issues/121
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local

Comment: Does this require that external client know which node a given broker is running on? So a pod, and only that pod for the Stateful, set can run on that node?

Comment: Yes to both questions. We run Kafka on a subset of our nodes and use node label matching. We also use pod affinity and antiaffinity to ensure that only one Kafka pod lands on a given node.

Comment: it's not working... i've tried this, and also changed `app: broker` to `app: kafka`. created a firewall rule on GKE and I get `failed: Operation timed out`.
any idea?

Comment: How do you set "advertised.listeners" so that they point to external node IPs?

Comment: @JasonKincl does it mean, that I have to set into Kafka advertised.listeners for example EXTERNAL_CLIENT://<cluster-ip>:3000 and that is it?

Comment: Regarding this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/ there is another disadvantage: "With each target weighted equally in terms of sending traffic to Nodes, external traffic is not equally load balanced across different Pods. The external load balancer is unaware of the number of Pods on each node that are used as a target."

Answer (score 22):

Note: I completely rewrote this post a year after the initial posting: 
1. Some of what I wrote is no longer relevant given updates to Kubernetes, and I figured it should be deleted to avoid confusing people. 
2. I now know more about both Kubernetes and Kafka and should be able to do a better explanation.

**Background Contextual Understanding of Kafka on Kubernetes:** 
 
Let's say a service of type cluster IP and stateful set are used to deploy a 5 pod Kafka cluster on a Kubernetes Cluster, because a stateful set was used to create the pods they each automatically get the following 5 inner cluster dns names, and then the kafka service of type clusterIP gives another inner cluster dns name.

```
M$*  kafka-0.my-kafka-headless-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local 
M$   kafka-1.my-kafka-headless-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local 
M *  kafka-2.my-kafka-headless-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local 
M *  kafka-3.my-kafka-headless-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local 
M$   kafka-4.my-kafka-headless-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
     kafka-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

^ Let's say you have 2 Kafka topics: $ and * 
Each Kafka topic is replicated 3 times across the 5 pod Kafka cluster 
(the ASCII diagram above shows which pods hold the replicas of the $ and * topics, M represents metadata)

4 useful bits of background knowledge: 
 1. .svc.cluster.local is the inner cluster DNS FQDN, but pods automatically are populated with the knowledge to autocomplete that, so you can omit it when talking via inner cluster DNS.
 2. kafka-x.my-kafka-headless-service.my-namespace inner cluster DNS name resolves to a single pod.
 3. kafka-service.my-namespace kubernetes service of type cluster IP acts like an inner cluster Layer 4 Load Balancer, and will round-robin traffic between the 5 kafka pods. 
 4. A critical Kafka specific concept to realize is when a Kafka client talks to a Kafka cluster it does so in 2 phases. Let's say a Kafka client wants to read the $ topic from the Kafka cluster. 
Phase 1: The client reads the kafka clusters metadata, this is synchronized across all 5 kafka pods so it doesn't matter which one the client talks to, therefore it can be useful to do the initial communication using kafka-service.my-namespace (which LB's and only forwards to a random healthy kafka pod)
Phase 2: The metadata tells the Kafka client which Kafka brokers/nodes/servers/pods have the topic of interest, in this case $ exists on 0, 1, and 4. So for Phase 2 the client will only talk directly to the Kafka brokers that have the data it needs.

**How to Externally Expose Pods of a Headless Service/Statefulset and Kafka specific Nuance:** 
Let's say that I have a 3 pod HashiCorp Consul Cluster spun up on a Kubernetes Cluster, I configure it so the webpage is enabled and I want to see the webpage from the LAN/externally expose it. There's nothing special about the fact that the pods are headless. You can use a Service of type NodePort or LoadBalancer to expose them as you normally would any pod, and the NP or LB will round robin LB incoming traffic between the 3 consul pods.

Because Kafka communication happens in 2 phases, this introduces some nuances where the normal method of externally exposing the statefulset's headless service using a single service of type LB or NP might not work when you have a Kafka Cluster of more than 1 Kafka pod.
 1. The Kafka client is expecting to speak directly to the Kafka Broker during Phase 2 communications. So instead of 1 Service of type NodePort, you might want 6 services of type NodePort/LB. 1 that will round-robin LB traffic for phase 1, and 5 with a 1:1 mapping to individual pods for Phase 2 communication. 
(If you run kubectl get pods --show-labels against the 5 Kafka pods, you'll see that each pod of the stateful set has a unique label, statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=kafka-0, and that allows you to manually create 1 NP/LB service that maps to 1 pod of a stateful set.) (Note this alone isn't enough) 
 2. When you install a Kafka Clusters on Kubernetes it's common for its default configuration to only support Kafka Clients inside the Kubernetes Cluster. Remember that Metadata from phase1 of a Kafka Client talking to a Kafka Cluster, well the kafka cluster may have been configured so that it's "advertised listeners" are made of inner cluster DNS names. So when the LAN client talks to an externally exposed Kafka Cluster via NP/LB, it's successful on phase1, but fails on phase 2, because the metadata returned by phase1 gave inner cluster DNS names as the means of communicating directly with the pods during phase 2 communications, which wouldn't be resolvable by clients outside the cluster and thus only work for Kafka Clients Inside the Cluster. So it's important to configure your kafka cluster so the "advertised.listeners" returned by the phase 1 metadata are resolvable by both clients external to the cluster and internal to the cluster.

**Clarity on where the Problem caused by Kafka Nuance Lies:** 
For Phase 2 of communication between Kafka Client -> Broker, you need to configure the "advertised.listeners" to be externally resolvable. 
This is difficult to pull off using Standard Kubernetes Logic, because what you need is for kafka-0 ... kafka-4 to each have a unique configuration/each to have a unique "advertised.listeners" that's externally reachable. But by default statefulsets are meant to have cookie-cutter configurations that are more or less identical.

**Solution to the Problem caused by Kafka Nuances:**
 
The Bitnami Kafka Helm Chart has some custom logic that allows each pod in the statefulset to have a unique "advertised.listerners" configuration. 
Bitnami Offers hardened Containers, according to Quay.io 2.5.0 only has a single High CVE, runs as non-root, has reasonable documentation, and can be externally exposed*, https://quay.io/repository/bitnami/kafka?tab=tags

The last project I was on I went with Bitnami, because security was the priority and we only had kafka clients that were internal to the kubernetes cluster, I ended up having to figure out how to externally expose it in a dev env so someone could run some kind of test and I remember being able to get it to work, I also remember it wasn't super simple, that being said if I were to do another Kafka on Kubernetes Project I'd recommend looking into Strimzi Kafka Operator, as it's more flexible in terms of options for externally exposing Kafka,  and it's got a great 5 part deep dive write up with different options for externally exposing a Kafka Cluster running on Kubernetes using Strimzi (via NP, LB, or Ingress) (I'm not sure what Strimzi's security looks like though, so I'd recommend using something like AnchorCLI to do a left shift CVE scan of the Strimzi images before trying a PoC) 

https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/04/17/accessing-kafka-part-1/

Comment: What about kubectl port forward? Can that be used?

Comment: I don't think kubectl port forward would work at all, I highly recommend reading this deep dive article to understand the problem better. https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/06/06/accessing-apache-kafka-in-strimzi-part-1-introduction/ Now that I know know kafka and kubernetes better, and that kafka is a bit of an edge case I'm going to massively edit my answer to be more clear.

Comment: @wwjdm I rewrote my entire post, I don't think kubectl port forward will work due to  the 2nd nuance.

Answer (score 2):

Change the service from a headless ClusterIP into a NodePort which would forward request to any of the *nodes* on a set port (30092 in my example) to port 9042 on the Kafkas. You would hit one of the pods, on random, but I guess that is fine.

20dns.yml becomes (something like this):

```
# A no longer headless service to create DNS records
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: broker
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 9092
  - nodePort: 30092
  # [podname].broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local
  selector:
    app: kafka
```

Disclaimer: You might need two services. One headless for the internal dns names and one NodePort for the external access. I haven't tried this my self.

Comment: That would do it. But theres an important constraint (which I forgot to clarify) that the external service trying to access the brokers be able to address the brokers specifically. From reading it seems to be antithetical to kubernetes in some ways, but wondering if at all possible. Even if it means creating individual services per broker backend.

Answer (score 1):

From the [kubernetes kafka documentation](https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka/tree/master/outside-services):

> Outside access with hostport
>
> An alternative is to use the hostport for the outside access. When
>   using this only one kafka broker can run on each host, which is a good
>   idea anyway.
>
> In order to switch to hostport the kafka advertise address needs to be
>   switched to the ExternalIP or ExternalDNS name of the node running the
>   broker. in kafka/10broker-config.yml switch to
>
> ```
> OUTSIDE_HOST=$(kubectl get node "$NODE_NAME" -o jsonpath='{.status.addresses[?(@.type=="ExternalIP")].address}')
> OUTSIDE_PORT=${OutsidePort}
> ```
>
> and in kafka/50kafka.yml add the hostport:
>
> ```
>     - name: outside
>       containerPort: 9094
>       hostPort: 9094
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating separate statefulset for each broker and separate service of type NodePort for each broker. Internal communication can happen on each individual service name. External communication can happen on NodePort address.