# Route Traffic Into Specific Pod of a Replica Set

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, traffic, kubernetes-statefulset

I need to route traffic (real-time audio/video) directly into specific container of pods. The number of pods should be scaled horizontally with a replica set. My solution now is to create a StatefulSet with as many NodePort-type services as there are pods.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: foobar
  name: foobar-app
spec:
  serviceName: foobar
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foobar
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: foobar
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: foobar:latest
        name: foobar
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: foobar-service-0
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: foobar-app-0
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30036
      port: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: foobar-service-1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: foobar-app-1
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30037
      port: 3000
```

Is this considered an acceptable solution or is there a better one for creating services for each pod?

Comment: why do you need this? what is the use case behind it?

Comment: I host a platform for video conferencing rooms and participants of the same room (instance running on a pod) must establish a direct video/audio connection to the room. Otherwise the participants media stream cannot be exchanged because they arrive at different rooms (instances).

Comment: You can look at [headless services](https://dev.to/kaoskater08/building-a-headless-service-in-kubernetes-3bk8) along with the statefulset

Comment: A couple considerations. 1) With the proposed solution, the pods will scale but not the services. You will have to automate the provisioning of a Service entry on every new pod. 2) When using headless services you have two options, querying via DNS and parsing the output OR fetching the Endpoints objects via the apiserver which will contain the pods IPs.

Comment: Headless services would be an option, but cannot directly exposed to the internet. I found a possible solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46468433/1628117): One NodePort service is used with one pod per node with cluster wide load balancing disabled (`externalTrafficPolicy=Local`).

Comment: If you set `externalTrafficPolicy=Local` only the node who has the service `NodePort` in the configured port will accept the connection, if the request goes to an other node the connection will be dropped. Based on this from where the connections is coming from? Your nodes has public IP's or do you have some kinda load balancer?

Comment: This should be the desired behaviour as I want to connect to the specific pod on a node via its IP and port without a load balancer.

Comment: @iY1NQ, That solved your issue? If yes, would be nice if you post an answer to help the community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments above I found the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456239/how-to-expose-a-headless-service-for-a-statefulset-externally-in-kubernetes/46468433#46468433) by using NodePort service targeting a StatefulSet with `externalTrafficPolicy=Local`. This disables the cluster wide load balancing between different nodes. The prerequisite is that only one pod of the stateful set may run per node, which can be achieved by setting [pod anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#always-co-located-in-the-same-node).

Comment: I don't want to use HPA at the moment. The need is to be able to reach each Pod directly (and uniquely) from outside of the cluster. For this purpose it was the right solution. Another question would be whether Kubernetes is actually the best choice for this scenario, but that is still open.

Comment: Using headless services would be the right solutions. Your's is closer to a workaround, and for kubernetes your app is just a candy, so I would discard if k8s is the right solution.