# Need n different endpoints for each replica in statefulset

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a statefulset of n replicas of my web service. I want to expose all n replicas of application externally through ingress.

```
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: webapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  serviceName: web-svc
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: httpd:2.4
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
```

I am using below service for that:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-svc
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  clusterIP: none
  ports:
  - port: 80
  name: web
  selector:
    app: web
```

Above headless service create 3 different endpoints, but how to expose these endpoints externally through ingress or any other way ?

There is a workaround of creating separate services for each pod name but that would be a manual effort of creating service and corresponding ingress URLs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to expose a headless service for a StatefulSet externally in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456239/how-to-expose-a-headless-service-for-a-statefulset-externally-in-kubernetes)

Comment: Hi @Neerej, does above comment answer your question or you're looking for something else?