# Kubernetes: expose headless behing an ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Why is not a good idea to expose via `ingress` an `headless` service?

I know, a headless service returns all ips behing service. Why this approach can't be populated via an `ingress < headless`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) the ClusterIP ServiceType services (including headless services ClusterIP “none”) are meant to be used internally (only reachable from within the cluster).

Exposing a headless service via ingress ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46456239/12014434)) first of all throws away one of the security layers, which allows hiding clusters internal networks and its objects behind the Cluster DNS.

This means that Exposing the internal IP address of a kubernetes pod makes it possible to guess the IP addresses of other objects on that network, which in turn can be valuable information for an attacker that already got past other security layers.

This alone may not be an issue, however in a case where a new vulnerability is discovered that is affecting another security layer, the knowledge of the internal IP address might be the deciding factor if the attack can be successful or not.