# Kafka service hosted on Kubernetes allows connection but not production of messages

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I have a Kubernetes cluster with an app that produces message to the service, the connection is able to happen, but no messages are being produced.

Here is my deployment and service config for Kafka:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka
          image: bitnami/kafka
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "1Gi"
              cpu: "1000m"
            limits:
              memory: "2Gi"
              cpu: "1500m"
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID
              value: "0"
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES
              value: controller,broker
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
              value: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS
              value: 0@kafka-service:9093
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES
              value: CONTROLLER
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE
              value: "true"
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_NUM_PARTITIONS
              value: "1"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
            - containerPort: 9093
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: kafka
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: broker-port
      port: 9092
      targetPort: 9092
    - protocol: TCP
      name: controller-port
      port: 9093
      targetPort: 9093
```

In all my code (golang with sarama), I am accessing Kafka via `kafka-service:9092` to connect and try producing messages, this setup worked with docker-compose and am trying to mimic it with Kubernetes.

My Kafka service itself is up and running, from the logs it says its ready to accept connections on 0.0.0.0:9092. Like I mentioned, the connection is working, but the producer logs this:

```
failed to produce message: dial tcp: lookup kafka-557b768ffc-78wjm on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host
```

kafka-557b768ffc-78wjm is the pod that's running Kafka right now.

Comment: Why define your own deployment? https://strimzi.io

Comment: Otherwise, read this for your error, and if you're using minikube, I think you need additional config for DNS to work https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/?ref=blog.claneys.net

Comment: Yeah I do think there is a dns issue, what I don’t understand is how the connection was made in the first place, doesn’t the producer produce to the same broker url? In my head it would make more sense if both worked, or none did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep this 2 major setups in mind when confifuring kafka in k8s.
1.Kafka should be deployed as statefulset
2.Service created in k8s should be headless service

Refer below link for suggestions.
[How to expose a headless service for a StatefulSet externally in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456239/how-to-expose-a-headless-service-for-a-statefulset-externally-in-kubernetes)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`, so it'll default to connect with the pod hostname name **after** the initial bootstrapping. https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Strimzi sets this up for you, and uses a StatefulSet rather than a Deployment to actually persist the Kafka data when the pod restarts